Proving A*Α=E for chosen coefficients.
I have this problem :
Let $ζ = e^{2πi} $
and $A \in Mat(n;\mathbb{C})$ so that $[A]_{jk} = \frac{ζ^{jk}}{\sqrt{n}}$ for every $j, k$. I have to prove $A^{*}A=E$. (Where $A^{*}=\bar{A}^t$.)
This is what i have :
We know $A^{*}= \bar{A}^t$
and we have $[A^{*}A]_{lk}=\Sigma [A^{*}]_{lj}[A]_{jk}=\Sigma [\bar{A}^{t}]_{lj}[A]_{jk}= [\bar{A}]_{jl}[A]_{jk}$
And I am stuck. When i developed this i found $\frac{1}{n}$ but this is not identity. Someone does have some tips, where should i go?

Can you tell us how you arrived at $1/n$? Also, are you saying that you got $1/n$ for a specific entry of the matrix?

As a hint, note that $[A^*A]_{\ell k}$ can be written as a geometric series for all $\ell \neq k$. For $\ell = k$, it is simply the norm of the $k$th column of $A$.

By the way, this matrix is essentially the same (specifically, permutation-similar) to the DFT-matrix.

After correcting a small typo, you've shown $[A^* A]_{lk} = \sum_j [\overline{A}]_{jl} [A]_{jk}$. Plugging in the values for the entries of $A$, we have
$$\sum_j \overline{\frac{\zeta^{jl}}{\sqrt{n}}} \frac{\zeta^{jk}}{\sqrt{n}}
= \frac{1}{n} \sum_{j=1}^n \overline{e^{2\pi ijl}} e^{2 \pi ijk}
= \frac{1}{n} \sum_{j=1}^n e^{2 \pi i j (k-l)}.$$
Now follow Ben Grossmann's hint to handle the case $l = k$ and $l \ne k$ separately.
